# My excerpt edit is not removed in the editing queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I just created the [nintendo-network-id](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-network-id) excerpt, but because I have not enough rep yet, it has to go through the queue and get accepted. However, immeditaly after I submitted the edit, I got the orange 1 in the upper right corner. I pressed it, and the queue turned out empty. That happens more often, but then the '1' disappears directly. Now it doesn't. I can keep reloading, but the '1' stays there.

So the problem is not that the queue appears empty while the number indicates it isn't, the problem is that my suggested tag excerpt edit is counted in the orange number, but is not in the queue.

Here a superfluous picture of it, you all know how it looks like:

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is showing everything in the review queue right now, even things you yourself cannot review (in this case, it is likely referring to the suggested wiki you made.) It's basically a side-wide reminder of "these things need to be dealt with", in the hopes that if the number gets too big, people will act on the things in the queues are they are able to (and have the ability/privileges to do so.)

It doesn't directly reflect the exact number of things you yourself can deal with, which is why it is showing you the queues are empty, because whatever that one thing is, it's not something you are yet able to handle.

Comment: So it is perfectly accepted and will not be 'fixed'?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the notification is working exactly as it is intended to, so no, there is nothing to fix. It's doing precisely what it was designed to do.

Comment: I mean that it would be better if there if that number was personalised, instead a site-wide reminder.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not how it is currently set up, and there are no plans to change the current implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

According to Nick Craver on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109634/179041):

> Yep, you could call this a bug, that's certainly valid. However, this value is displayed on every page load and cached for the system overall.
>
> It's a classic trade-off case between accuracy and performance, and in this case we're okay with 99% accuracy vs a severe degradation and complication on the performance side. I wouldn't expect this to change any time soon, it'll stay this way for performance reasons.

---

Note however, that the 'review count' has been removed from the top bar. Instead, we get a red dot on the top bar when there are many things to review, and grey dots in the menu when there are only a couple:

[image: Review Queues Red Dot]